# What is the purpose of /usr/share/icons/gnome/scalable/mimetypes/?

Tags: gnome, lubuntu, icons, mime-type

*Adding an Icon* section in [AddingMimeTypes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddingMimeTypes) has this:

> Now we need to associate an icon with the MIME type. Get an SVG icon
>   and name it "text/extension .svg", or whatever your modified MIME type
>   is named; this will be the icon to represent all instances of the MIME
>   type on your system. For our python example, this is a good choice.
>   Rename the .svg file so that the it matches "text/x-python.svg" (or
>   "insertYourMIMEtype.svg") so that the slashes are replaced with "-"
>   and there are no capital letters.
>
> Then simply run the following command, with 'text/x-python' replaced
>   with your MIME type.
>
> `sudo cp text-x-python.svg /usr/share/icons/gnome/scalable/mimetypes`
>
> Relogin and all files ending in the MIME extension will display with
>   that icon.

In my Lubuntu 13.04 system I see very few icons in this folder compared to the MIME types I know are present in the system:

```
[08:31 AM] /usr/share/icons/gnome/scalable/mimetypes $ ls
application-certificate-symbolic.svg  libreoffice4.0-oasis-drawing-template.svg       libreoffice4.0-oasis-spreadsheet.svg           package-x-generic-symbolic.svg
application-rss+xml-symbolic.svg      libreoffice4.0-oasis-formula.svg                libreoffice4.0-oasis-spreadsheet-template.svg  text-mkd.svg
audio-x-generic-symbolic.svg          libreoffice4.0-oasis-master-document.svg        libreoffice4.0-oasis-text.svg                  text-x-generic-symbolic.svg
libreoffice4.0-oasis-database.svg     libreoffice4.0-oasis-presentation.svg           libreoffice4.0-oasis-text-template.svg         video-x-generic-symbolic.svg
libreoffice4.0-oasis-drawing.svg      libreoffice4.0-oasis-presentation-template.svg  libreoffice4.0-oasis-web-template.svg          x-office-calendar-symbolic.svg
[08:31 AM] /usr/share/icons/gnome/scalable/mimetypes $
```

(I installed LibreOffice which isn't included by default on Lubuntu.)

For example, icons for html and pdf aren't here though they are present in, for example, `/usr/share/icons/lubuntu/mimes/16`.

Then, if one compares the sizes by looking at the contents of the `.svg` files, the icons for LibreOffice components are ~ 256x256 whereas the others are 16x16.

**In short**:
What is the purpose of `/usr/share/icons/gnome/scalable/mimetypes/`?
Why are so few icons there?
Why do the sizes differ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the purpose of /usr/share/icons/gnome/scalable/mimetypes/?

The purpose of the x/y/mimetypes folder is to provide icons for the mimetypes (all files).

> Why are so few icons there?

In the particular case of that folder it's because most software supplies their own mimetype icons, and they usually put the icons in `usr/share/icons/hicolor/mimetypes/[size]` instead of the Gnome folders.

> Why do the sizes differ?

- [Why do some icon themes have so many different sizes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/299377/why-do-some-icon-themes-have-so-many-different-sizes/299382#299382)